# Failure to install ruby gems with rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv-gemset

I can't install any Ruby gems. I am using rbenv and when I use `gem install rails`, I get a permission error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory
```

I have been trying to install Rails for days now, even with RVM.

I am pretty sure the problem lies with my `$PATH` but I do not know how to change this.

I am running Ruby version 2.0.0p247.

Comment: or maybe you don't have write permissions to that folder?

Comment: Run `gem env`, and append the output to your question by editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try `gem update --system`, and try to gem install again, if it fails, post your log.